# Grade School Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, music

### Arithmetic

> - 47 + 28 = ?
> - 107 + 92 + 25 - 7 + 53 = ?
> - 6 + 1 + 53 = ?
> - 26 + 92 = ?
> - 16 + 92 + 53 = ?
> - 22 + 68 + 88 = ?
> - 23 + 85 + 52 + 7 = ?
> - 74 + 85 + 68 = ?

### Reading

> - Ehad fo ocrn
> - Eredantl estfor malmam
> - Iekam isuoidolem isdnuos
> - Esp noitseq
> - Tovey brveick brveand
> - Low un weucht; soirge of ullimunatuon
> - Fivast playeva characteva fvaom Stvaeet Fighteva
> - Gedi duru

### Writing

[image]

---

Please answer the following question:

> How will they describe this puzzle?

Comment: If I had to guess, they'd describe it as elementary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They would describe it as

> Elementary

**Arithmetic**

> Interpreting the numbers as atomic numbers of chemical elements and using their abbreviations, giving names of classical elements in different languages.

47 + 28 = ?

> Ag + Ni = AGNI (Javanese for fire)

107 + 92 + 25 - 7 + 53 = ?

> Bh + U + Mn - N + I = BHUMI (Sanskrit for earth)

6 + 1 + 53 = ?

> C + H + I = CHI (Japanese godai term for earth)

26 + 92 = ?

> Fe + U = FEU (French for fire)

16 + 92 + 53 = ?

> S + U + I = SUI (Japanese for water)

22 + 68 + 88 = ?

> Ti + Er + Ra = TIERRA (Spanish for earth)

23 + 85 + 52 + 7 = ?

> V + At + Te + N = VATTEN (Swedish for water)

74 + 85 + 68 = ?

> W + At + Er = WATER (English for water)

**Reading**

> These puzzles are decode-solve-encode giving names of classical elements in different languages.

Ehad fo ocrn

> = HEAD OF CORN = EAR = AER (Irish for air)

Eredantl estfor malmam

> = ANTLERED FOREST MAMMAL = DEER = ERDE (German for earth)

Iekam isuoidolem isdnuos

> = MAKE MELODIOUS SOUNDS = SING = IGNIS (Latin for fire)

Esp noitseq

> = POSE QUESTION = ASK = KA (Japanese godai term for fire)

Tovey brveick brveand

> = TOY BRICK BRAND = LEGO = LEVEGO (Hungarian for air)

Low un weucht; soirge of ullimunatuon

> = LOW IN WEIGHT; SOURCE OF ILLUMINATION = LIGHT = LUCHT (Dutch for air)

Fivast playeva characteva fvaom Stvaeet Fighteva

> = FIRST PLAYER CHARACTER FROM STREET FIGHTER = RYU = VAYU (Hindi for air)

Gedi duru

> JEDI GURU = YODA = VODA (Czech/Slovak/Finnish/Russian/Serbo-Croat/Slovene for water)

**Writing**

> The different answers fit into the grid, with red spaces for words meaning FIRE, green spaces for words meaning EARTH, yellow spaces for words meaning AIR and blue space for words meaning WATER. Reading down the contiguous column then give ASK THE LOCAL GENTRY which resolves to "they will say it's ELEMENTARY" per the lyrics of the song "[Love and Marriage](https://lyricsjonk.com/frank-sinatra-love-and-marriage.html)" (thanks to [Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil) for this observation and  the grid below).
>
>  [image]

Comment: I've added an image for you, and also you'll find the answer on the sixth line of [this song](https://lyricsjonk.com/frank-sinatra-love-and-marriage.html) :) no idea for the Gedi Duru line

Comment: One of your guesses for Gedi duru is correct. Knowing that, you might be able to back solve the clue...

Comment: Thanks, I think that I now have a complete solution (though I don't know how to update @BeastlyGerbil's excellent image).

Comment: Updated it now, good job! I'd only solved the maths bit and about half the reading when you posted, but I hadn't noticed that the answers were all elements!

Comment: @DanielS nice job! Thank you for solving.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil thank you for the grid solution image and making the connection to the final answer!